# split command and putting output to the specific pattern files

Tags: linux, bash

when we use following command:

```
split -l  1000 test.txt
```

the result would be xaa xab xac ...

how can I put the out put to pattern made by me?
for example:
I want to do:

```
split -l 1000 test.txt
```

and the result should be:

```
0001 0002 0003 0004 ... 10000 10001...
```

I want to use numbers instead of xaa etc...
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
split -l 1000 -d --suffix-length=5 test.txt ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the man page for [`split`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) and with GNU `split` (but not others, such as BSD `split` as found on Mac OS X), you can use:

```
-d 100
```

to specify numeric suffixes starting at 100 (for example; or you can omit the number to start at 1), and:

```
-a 4
```

to specify that the suffixes should be (at least) 4 digits, and you can specify the prefix after the file name:

```
split -l 1000 -d 100 -a 4 test.txt prefix.
```

So, for your example, you could simply write:

```
split -d -a 4 test.txt ''
```

(since the default split is 1000 lines, which you specified explicitly as `-l 1000`).